# Using Boost with C++14 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, gcc4.9

When I am compiling my code with C++11 support (using the `-std=c++11` flag) and use non-header-only Boost libraries, then I need to have Boost compiled with `-std=c++11`. This is because Boost has some interface differences in header files when C++11 is enabled, and some function signatures are different for the different C++ standards.

My question is whether the same is true with C++14 (using g++ 4.9, with the `-std=c++1y flag), or is it safe to use Boost compiled with C++11 for a program compiled with C++14?

Comment: Nothing will be safe until the C++14 standard is finalised, which, at the time of writing, is not case. As its scope is broadly limited to fixes to C++11 I'd imagine you would get away with using -std=c++11.

Comment: I don't think that C++14 will be 100% retro-compatible with C++11, there is at least 1 case that, at this point in time, it's being handled differently in this 2 standards ( of course C++14 it's not here yet so everything about it is hypothetical ).

Answer (score 4):

This is a very broad question that is difficult to answer definitively, because

- Boost is a federation of libraries, many of which are over decade old
- there are quite a lot of backward compatibilities that could in principle happen, some detected by the compiler, and some only by unit tests
- many Boost libraries are actually C++98 implementations of C++11/14 features (both library and compiler functionality), so that you would not need to use this in a C++11/14 project.
- Boost itself is very much debating at which pace the library should be updated to C++11/14, whether V2 versions of libraries should be written that fully take advantage of C++11/14, and even whether new C++11/14 libraries should offer backward C++98 compatibility

You might want to closely read your compiler errors (if any) and compare them to the list of breaking changes listed below. Furthermore, I would recommend following the [Boost test harness](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/developer/summary.html) for finding suspect compiler/library combinations that apply to your system.

Some relevant Q&A's here:

1. [What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6399615/819272)
2. [What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23980929/819272)
3. [Relevant boost features vs C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8851670/819272)
4. [How well does boost use c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13608403/819272)